# How to pass value in link function of a angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Dear All I have directive

```
function percentview($compile) {
    var linker = function (scope, element) {

        var controldef = "";
        switch (scope.percentage.state) {
            case 'stable':
                controldef = ' <span class="text-yellow font-17">' +
                    '  <i>0%</i>' +
                    '<i class="fa "></i> </span>';



                break;
            case 'up':
                controldef = ' <span class="text-issue font-17">' +
                   '  <i>+ {{percentage.percentage}}%</i>' +
                   '<i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> </span>';
                break;
            case 'down':
                controldef = ' <span class="text-green font-17">' +
                  '  <i- {{percentage.percentage}}%</i>' +
                  '<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i> </span>';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        element.html($compile(controldef));
    };
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',

        scope: {
            percentage: '='
        },
        link: linker

    }

    return directive;
}

percentview.$inject = ['$compile'];
angular
 .module('app')
 .directive('percentview', percentview);
```

html://

```
<percentview percentage="percentiles[0]"></percentview>
```

but when i run the code i am getting the error  *scope.percentage is undefined* i logged the scope object in link function and can see the property (object) called percentage with all values.

How i can pass a object in link function. or what is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 1):

The pass of variable to link function seems Ok to me.

If you pass a literal it works fine as you can see in the jbin below, maybe you have scope issues and percentiles[0] its not available on that scope

http://jsbin.com/zodeva/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score -1):

Can you try `element.percentage.state`?
As I can see percentage is an attribute of the element.